# Trying to create a line chart with two lines for similar data from same data table

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to create a line chart in Power BI with two lines representing counts by date.  The data is pulled from a single data table.  I am trying to show two lines, one representing an incoming count and one representing an outgoing count.  Each record has a unique identifier (IN).  So, the chart would have months on the x-axis pulled from a date table I created.  One line would show the count of incoming IN for each month, and the other line would show the count of outgoing IN for each month.  When I try to do this, both lines show the same count.  I've tried a number of different measures, but nothing seems to work.  These are the latest that I'm trying.

```
Intake by Date = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('sysadm kennel (2)'[impound_no]),'sysadm kennel (2)'[intake_date])
Outcome by Date = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('sysadm kennel (2)'[impound_no]),'sysadm kennel (2)'[outcome_date])
```

I'm pretty new to Power BI, so I don't have a full grasp of how to create measures.  The Intake By Date seems to be the correct one, but the Outcome by Date is showing the same number.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your model. Create an active relationship between Calendar and DataTable to your Intake; Add an inactive relationship between Calendar and DataTable to your Outcome; In measure for [Outcome by Date] use USERELATIONSHIP('Calendar'[Date],DataTable[OutcomeDate])

https://dax.guide/userelationship/